# Flutter Accidentaly deleted pubspec.yaml file, getting "Target of URI doesn't exist" error

Tags: flutter

I deleted pubspec.yaml by accident, but I put it back to the app folder, but I cannot build my app. Im constantly getting "Target of URI doesn't exist" error. Running flutter pub get works fine but doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the IDE? Also, does `pub packages get` run without errors? [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17016#issuecomment-384911981) they discuss kind of a similar issue.

Comment: I tried restarting VSCode, but it doesn''t work. "flutter pub get" runs with no errors.

Comment: In this case, if the project is small, I would create a new one and would copy everything into the new project. 
Have you used any Version Control? You can use it to restore the files you accidentally deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Make sure while you **don't have** any additional copies of `.packages` and `pubspec.lock` files. Its best to just delete all `.packages` and `pubspec.lock` files and leave just `pubspec.yaml` and then run `flutter pub get`